# java regex lookbehind how to cut out part of the pre-search result?

Tags: java, regex, lookbehind

I want to know how to match a string in a specified region: for example, I hava a C++ code snippet:

```
/*
    This is .... bla bla bla...int, float,...
    @author: Tom
*/
int a;
float b;
```

then I want to find out the keywords like `int`,`float`outside the comment, how to? I was thinking if I could use pre-search. But a simple sample, `\b\w+(?<=er)\b` matches words like 'worker','super',how to do if I only want the sub string of these results before `er`.And another example, if I only need to match the line comment in c++ code, if I use `//.*?\n`,the `\n`is also in the result, but I don't need it...
**update:**
I don't know if I have explained my problem clearly, and i don't know how to give a title to my question... :(

Comment: You can not and/or should not do this with regular expressions.

Comment: So you're matching `//.*?\n` but are surprised that `\n` is part of the match?

Comment: @Tomalak no, I know `\n` is part of the match, but i'm finding a way to only match the comment text before `\n` and i need to use `\n` as the flag of the end of the comment, i think catch group is what i need, and i will try to do more on it if it really can fix my problem

Comment: @Ggicci No, you don't need to include the `\n`. If you use `//.*` it will match to the end of the line, excluding the `\n`. Your expression needs it because you use non-greedy matching `.*?`. (That's what I meant with in my comment beneath Daniel Hilgarth's answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really shouldn't parse source code with regular expressions. Use the right tool for the job... Regular expressions aren't the right tool, because it is very hard to take the context into account. You already observed this problem yourself.

Having said this, generally, you can use groups in your regular expressions to get only part of a match.

For example, the regular expression `a(b)c` will match the string `abc`, but the result will contain two groups.

1. The first group is the complete match `abc`.
2. The second group is the first sub-group `b`.

The example to match the single line comment in C++ could look like this:

```
//(.*?)\n
```

The first sub-group would than contain only the comment text.

Comment: +1 *"You really shouldn't parse source code with regular expressions."* - This is *especially* true if you only have a very weak grip of regular expressions to begin with.